# cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a single entity name business which is used by two different UserBusinessRole,BusinessInterest.I want to add foreign key for business entity in UserBusinessRole which is not linked to BusinessInterest but with business which is owned by BusinessInterest therefor i cant set a foreign key in UserBusinessRole. getting an error System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type 'Business' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists.'

```
internal class BusinessInterestEntityConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration <BusinessInterest> {
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder < BusinessInterest > builder) {
    builder.OwnsOne(x =>x.Business, sa =>{
      sa.Property(x =>x.FundsWarningLevel).HasColumnType(SqlDbType.Money.ToString());

      sa.HasOne(x =>x.CDF).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.CDFId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    });
  }
}

internal class UserBusinessRoleEntityConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration <UserBusinessRole> {
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserBusinessRole> builder) {
      builder.HasOne(x =>x.Business).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x =>x.BusinessId).IsRequired();
  }
}
```

Comment: The code posted should only be run once.  There is a mapping file (EDMX) which maps the database tables/fields with the c# classes.  The code above modifies the EDMX.  So once a key is added you cannot add it a second time.

Comment: actually its inside in the OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
  using modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BusinessInterestEntityConfiguration());

Comment: So you only create a Model once.  What happens if you want to modify an existing Model.  Do you run entire code or just what needs to be updated?  Running a Create method when the object is already created will add duplicates and give exceptions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you help me with how to give a foreign key to entity which is owned by someone other entity? in upper example i want to give a foreign key to business entity which is owned by Business Interest. Or set property name without own entity?

Comment: i was own the entity for replace this line of entity framework builder.Property(x => x.SundayHours.IsClosed).HasColumnName("IsClosedSunday");   is there any other way to achive the same thing?

Comment: I usually use the VS tools to create the mapping and refresh the mapping.  I don't do it from a c# application.

Comment: Is there no other entity that references the Business entity? By the error message it seems there is some other entity, where you didn't configure the relation as an ownership.

Comment: that errror was at UserBusinessRoleEntityConfiguration.